# dataframe should contain multiple rows, but always contain a single row after appending

Tags: python, dataframe, google-maps

in this code, matrixdf should contain a big dataset because, i am appending matrixdf2, a single row in the dataframe. but after simulation, i have observed, it's still a single row.  what can be the problem here. at first i initialized, then the loop started.

```
def distance_count(self):
  m = self.client.distance_matrix(self.origins, self.destinations)
  matrixdf = json_normalize(m,['rows','elements']) 
  print("init print")
  print(matrixdf)
  next_time = time.time()
  for i in range(5):
   matrix = self.client.distance_matrix(self.origins, self.destinations)
   matrixdf2 = json_normalize(matrix,['rows','elements'])
   print("row1")
   print(matrixdf2)
   matrixdf.append(matrixdf2)
   print("full")
   print(matrixdf)
   i = i + 5
   next_time += i
   time.sleep(max(0, next_time - time.time()))
  matrixdf.to_csv('dataset.csv')
  files.download('dataset.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are instating a new matrix object multiple times inside the loop `for`, so you are appending the new data always to a new object.

Try to remove this line of the loop, as following:

```
def distance_count(self):
  m = self.client.distance_matrix(self.origins, self.destinations)
  matrixdf = json_normalize(m,['rows','elements']) 
  print("init print")
  print(matrixdf)
  next_time = time.time()
  #PUT HERE
  matrix = self.client.distance_matrix(self.origins, self.destinations)
  for i in range(5):
   # REMOVE FROM LOOP
   #matrix = self.client.distance_matrix(self.origins, self.destinations)
   matrixdf2 = json_normalize(matrix,['rows','elements'])
   print("row1")
   print(matrixdf2)
   matrixdf.append(matrixdf2)
   print("full")
   print(matrixdf)
   i = i + 5
   next_time += i
   time.sleep(max(0, next_time - time.time()))

  matrixdf.to_csv('dataset.csv')
  files.download('dataset.csv')
```

Comment: but I have to append this data, that's the main job of this function, in this line, I am calling an API, and get the data. by this loop, I am actually maintaining a time interval